# How to use a rewrite map to replace a single querystring value with IIS 7 URL Rewrite

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

We have incoming URL's with querystring's like this:

```
?query=word&param=value
```

where we would like to use a rewrite map to build a table of substitution values for "word".

For example:

```
word = newword
```

such that the new querystring would be:

```
?query=newword&param=value
```

"word" may be any urlencoded value, including %'s

I'm having trouble with the regex match and substitution - I seem to get it to match, but then the substituted value doesn't get passed through.

My current rule looks like:

```
Match URL:   Matches the Pattern:  .*
Conditions:  match all:
Condition 1:   {QUERY_STRING} matches "query=(.+)\&+?(.+)$"
Condition 2:   {rewritemap:{C:1}} matches the pattern (.+)
```

track capture across groups.

Action: rewrite:

```
rewrite url:  ?query={C:1}&param=value
```

(I've hard coded the &param=value because it isn't changing... having that just pass through from the input would be ideal, I was just being lazy)

So write now using failed request tracking I can see it match, and seemingly replace with the mapped value, but then the url that is output still has the original value.